# How to ignore the Base SDK for a single pod

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

For an iOS project that requires iOS 5.1 I want to include an Pod that requires at least iOS 6.0 (ARChromeActivity). When I'm trying to install this Pod I only get the message:

```
[!] The platform of the target `Pods` (iOS 5.1) is not compatible with `ARChromeActivity (1.0.0)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 6.0.
```

How can I include this Pod in my project anyway and ignore the base SDK for this single Pod?

Comment: While @Keith has answered the question you asked - I'll note that this probably won't end up working, as ARChromeActivity subclasses a class that wasn't introduced until iOS 6, per : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011976

Comment: I know that ARChromeActivity requires iOS 6. But there is no reason to include it in an App that is built for iOS 5 and only use it when the user uses iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: The purpose of the podspec's platform attribute is to make sure the library isn't installed with a version of the OS it has not been tested on by its maintainers. That being said, in your `Podfile` you can simple change the platform requirements to what you want to emulate for example,

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
```

Obviously that is for all your pods not just a single one but you can see why that feature doesn't exist. In the newer versions of CocoaPods you actually don't need that line at all and it will detect your target version from your project, obviously since you're trying to use code that's not meant for the version you're using that wouldn't help you but it's typically quite useful.

**Edit:**

Alternatively you can edit the spec's source directly. In this case open `~/.cocoapods/master/ARChromeActivity/1.0.0/ARChromeActivity.podspec` in some editor and change:

```
s.platform     = :ios, '6.0'
```

to

```
s.platform     = :ios, '5.0'
```

Then run pod install

Comment: But this will change the target platform of my Pods project. As a result the App will crash when you are trying to run it on an older version of iOS. I could change the deployment target of the Pod project manually but it will be changed again as soon as I call pod install again, something that could be easily overlooked.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do would be not to change s.platform in the Podspec but to fix the `s.io.deployment` target:

```
s.ios.deployment_target = '5.0'
```